# What is equivalent of Matlab nan( ) in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, nan

this is my MATLAB code with the following output:

```
pad=nan(1,5)

pad =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I want to do the same operation in python, I tried `np.isnan(1,6)` but this is not working. what should I used to get the same results. thank you

Comment: Did you try `np.nan`?

Comment: i tried this like np.nan(5) also np.nan(1,5) but it show this error: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.full()` to create a multi-dimensional array pre-populated with the same values:

```
np.full((1, 5), np.nan)
```

which produces:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Comment: why not np.full(5, np.nan) ?  this give us array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])

Comment: @user20191650: Because the two-argument form of Matlab's `nan()` returns a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.zeros(N) + numpy.nan, where N is the number of NaN you want in your array.

```
import numpy as np

N = 6
nan_array = np.zeros(N) + np.nan
```

Will produce the following array -

`[array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])]`